# Place the filled battery inside the image accurately so it scales and aligns for different screens

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uikit, cgrect

[image]

I want to achieve the above in Swift3 where 60% is the current battery level of the user. The green color must be filled as the battery level increases. I already have a image of the 2 borders i.e. the outermost border, and border within that as 1 image. I want to place the filled color within that. I am having trouble and have to hardcode values as its not getting aligned properly.

The image which is the outermost border and innerborder is called battery which I have placed in xcode as 3x, 2x, 1x.

```
let view1 = LevelView(frame: CGRect(x: battery.frame.origin.x,
                                        y: battery,
                                        width: battery.layer.preferredFrameSize().width - 25,
                                        height: battery.layer.preferredFrameSize().height / 2 - 5),
                          level: CGFloat(BatteryUtil.sharedInstance.batteryLevel()))

    battery.layer.addSublayer(view1.layer)
```

Here is LevelView code:

```
import UIKit

class LevelView : UIView {

  init(frame: CGRect, level: CGFloat) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    //self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    let levelLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    levelLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: frame.origin.x,
                                                       y: frame.origin.y,
                                                       width: frame.width * level,
                                                       height: frame.height),
                                   cornerRadius: 0).cgPath
    levelLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 148/255.0, green: 201/255.0, blue: 61/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(levelLayer)

  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("Required, but Will not be called in a Playground")
  }
}
```

I'm quite new to this, how to make it the desired way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest getting rid of the bitmap images and just draw the entire shape.

Try this to start, then adjust settings as needed:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class LevelView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var batteryLevel: CGFloat = 0.6 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        drawLevel(batteryLevel: batteryLevel)
    }

    func drawLevel(batteryLevel: CGFloat = 0.6) {
        //// General Declarations
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!


        //// Variable Declarations
        let width: CGFloat = 334 * batteryLevel
        let batteryLabelText = "\(Int(round(batteryLevel * 100)))" + "%"

        //// White Rectangle Drawing
        let whiteRectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 24.5, y: 20.5, width: 334, height: 118))
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        whiteRectanglePath.fill()
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        whiteRectanglePath.lineWidth = 5
        whiteRectanglePath.stroke()


        //// Green Rectangle Drawing
        let greenRectangleRect = CGRect(x: 24.5, y: 20.5, width: width, height: 118)
        let greenRectanglePath = UIBezierPath(rect: greenRectangleRect)
        UIColor.green.setFill()
        greenRectanglePath.fill()
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        greenRectanglePath.lineWidth = 5
        greenRectanglePath.stroke()
        let greenRectangleStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        greenRectangleStyle.alignment = .center
        let greenRectangleFontAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)!,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: greenRectangleStyle,
            ]

        let greenRectangleTextHeight: CGFloat = batteryLabelText.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: greenRectangleRect.width, height: CGFloat.infinity), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: greenRectangleFontAttributes, context: nil).height
        context.saveGState()
        context.clip(to: greenRectangleRect)
        batteryLabelText.draw(in: CGRect(x: greenRectangleRect.minX, y: greenRectangleRect.minY + (greenRectangleRect.height - greenRectangleTextHeight) / 2, width: greenRectangleRect.width, height: greenRectangleTextHeight), withAttributes: greenRectangleFontAttributes)
        context.restoreGState()


        //// Outer Rectangle Drawing
        let outerRectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 7, y: 7, width: 372, height: 146), cornerRadius: 20)
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        outerRectanglePath.lineWidth = 12
        outerRectanglePath.stroke()


        //// Bezier Drawing
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 396, y: 53))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 396, y: 109))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 407, y: 98))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 407, y: 64))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 396, y: 53))
        bezierPath.close()
        UIColor.gray.setFill()
        bezierPath.fill()
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 12
        bezierPath.lineCapStyle = .round
        bezierPath.lineJoinStyle = .round
        bezierPath.stroke()
    }


}
```

You can add it directly to your storyboard if you want.

[image: LevelView item in storyboard]

Add a reference from your storyboard to your view controller.

[image: Add a reference from your storyboard to your view controller]

Comment: If I directly add to the storyboard then how will I set the battery level as that needs to be done from code?

Comment: Just create a reference to it from the storyboard to your view controller. Then you can call levelView.batteryLevel = BatteryUtil.sharedInstance.batteryLevel() (assuming that returns a CGFloat from 0 to 1) You don't have to add it to the storyboard, you could just create it in code and add it as a subview. Either way works. Just keep a reference to it so that you can update the battery level.

Comment: what element do you drag to assign the levelview to? as mine gets cut out

Comment: What setting should I add so that the image gets filled in the uiview?

Comment: From the view controller in the scene hierarchy, control-drag to the battery. If you've not added references before you might want to watch a tutorial on that. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-ZaRC8L6uE or just Google "adding outlet references in Xcode"

Comment: It's a UIView subclass, so you can set any background color you need, or just leave it transparent.

Comment: I already added the reference, but after I add the reference the image gets set in the uiview although it's cut out. I even tried to set width, height to uniview but it wouldn't show the entire battery on it but the cut out view.

Comment: The last section on `//// Bezier Drawing
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()` does not get drawn for me

Comment: Might be getting clipped off, be sure to set the view size large enough. You may need to go through and make all the dimensions smaller if your limited on space. Currently, if width is less than 407, it will get clipped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147755/discussion-between-fscore-and-picciano).